# Binding a JavaFx ListView's selection index to an integer property

Tags: java, listview, data-binding, javafx

Is it possible to bind (one-way) a ListView's selection index or item to a property?

I can get a ReadOnlyIntegerProperty with this call, but it's a ReadOnlyProperty which does not have the bind methods you see in `ObjectProperty`, `StringProperty`, etc.

```
myListView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty()
```

How do I go about binding an Integer Property to my ListView's selected index property?

Comment: Even though you've accepted an answer, you should still probably clarify this question, to make it more helpful to other users. It looks like you are wanting to "Bind an integer to ListView's selection", rather than the other way round (the other way round is how you have it in both the title and first sentence of the question). Also: "I can understand not permitting biDirectionalBinding since it's read only... . And, why isn't two way binding permissible" is self-contradictory. (What did you really mean here?)

Comment: @James_D I agree. I've edited to clarify the title and question.

Comment: The title is still the opposite of the answer you accepted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can understnad not permitting biDirectionalBinding since it's read
>   only, but how can i do one way binding?

Try:

```
IntegerProperty property = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
property.bind(myListView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty());
```

Comment: In most cases, if you're going to do this, the `property` becomes redundant, because you can just expose the `selectedIndexProperty` for the same effect. Also, note that while this appears to be what the OP wants, it's not what (s)he actually asked: this "binds the property to the selection", it doesn't "bind the selection to the property".

Answer (score 4):

The API exposes the `selectedIndex` as a `ReadOnlyProperty` because it doesn't want to expose the `bind` method that is part of the `Property` API. The reason it doesn't want to expose the `bind` method is that the `ListView` needs to be able to set the property when the user clicks on it. If the `bind` method were part of the API, and the programmer called `listView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().bind(...)`, then runtime errors would be generated whenever the user clicked on the list.

Because the `bindBidirectional` is also part of the `Property` API, but not the `ReadOnlyProperty` API, this means that you also cannot bidirectionally bind the `selectedIndex`.

You can achieve the same effect as bidirectional binding using two listeners:

```
IntegerProperty property = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
ListView<?> listView = new ListView<?>();

// change property when selection changes:
listView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((obs, oldIndex, newIndex) ->
    property.set(newIndex.intValue()));

// change selection when property changes:
property.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
    listView.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(newValue.intValue()));
```

If you just want to bind the selected item index to the property, you only need the second listener.

If you just want to bind the property to the selected item index, and you are not going to set the property by other means, then of course you can just bind the property:

```
IntegerProperty property = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
property.bind(listView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty());
```

(Though in this case, you could always just reference the `selectedIndexProperty` directly if your design allows.)

Comment: I don't need the second listener if I don't want two way binding, right? I believe that listener is setting the selection if someone were to have modified the IntegerProperty, yes?

Comment: Yes, correct in both cases. But if you only want the property to change when the selection changes, and you are not going to set the property directly, you can use a binding for that.

Comment: Yes, what you said is actually what I want. The info you provided is helpful though. So, I believe I can just do @Puce 's answer to do the one way binding.

Comment: But bidirectionally bound properties can be set, AFAIK, can't they?

Comment: @Puce, yes, they can. But `ReadOnlyProperty`s cannot be bidirectionally bound, and regular `Property`s have a `bind` method, which I think the API wanted to avoid exposing here as it would break things.

Comment: Yes, but the question was why is it a ReadOnlyProperty, if it weren't it could be bound bidirectionally and your answer says it can't be bound (bidirectionally) because it is a ReadOnlyProperty...

Comment: Well, the question is quite confused: "I can understand not permitting biDirectionalBinding since it's read only... . And, why isn't two way binding permissible?" :). But I tried to clarify the answer anyway.